# Stuck on output error in java

Tags: java

I'm having an output error in my java program. 
My program is a simple guessing game which takes a number from the user and also creates a random number too. Then it finds the difference between those numbers and displays it to the user.
And i am a beginner so i would appreciate simple guidance please. Thank you.
This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class RandomGuessMatch
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int random_Number, user_Number, difference;
      String random;

      random_Number = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 100);

      user_Number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
         "Please guess a number between 1 to 5." + "Please input your number",
         "Guessing Game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

      difference = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
         "The difference between my number and your number is " + user_Number - random_Number,
         "Guessing Game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

      boolean valid = random_Number == user_Number;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
         "Does your number and my number match?" + "\n" + valid,
         "Guessing Game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
}
```

And this is the error i get(i use jGrasp):

```
RandomGuessMatch.java:13: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
      user_Number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,

RandomGuessMatch.java:18: error: bad operand types for binary operator '-'
         "The difference between my number and your number is " + user_Number - random_Number,
```

Comment: Those are *two* errors. 1) `JOptionPane` does not contain `INFORMATION_DIALOG`, it has [`INFORMATION_MESSAGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#INFORMATION_MESSAGE). 2) `"..." + user_Number` is a string. You cannot subtract a number from a string. Use "..." + (user_Number - random_Number)`.

Comment: I have corrected the first error but the suggestion u did for the string thing its still giving me error.

Comment: @dhke Actually `user_Number` is an int, `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`, returns a string so it won't compile too

Comment: @BackSlash Add `difference`. Yeah, that's the third error ...

Comment: Thank you @dhke for your advice.

Comment: And @BackSlash thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as show below.
This code is working.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class RandomGuessMatch {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int random_Number, difference;
    String user_Number;
    String random;

    random_Number = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    System.out.println(random_Number);

    user_Number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Please guess a number between 1 to 5." + "Please input your number", "Guessing Game",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "The difference between my number and your number is "
                    + (Integer.parseInt(user_Number) - random_Number),
            "Guessing Game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    boolean valid = (random_Number == Integer.parseInt(user_Number));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Does your number and my number match?" + "\n" + valid, "Guessing Game",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
}
```

Comment: @Kishore i improved them. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

**Error 1:**

there is no argument like `INFORMATION_DIALOG` in `JOptionPane` class, also you are trying to store store `JOptionPane` result into Integer type but it should be String type.

**Error 2:**

As you already concatenate the String so you need to subtract integers like this `(user_Number - random_Number)`

Comment: The problem is solved and thanks for your help @Omore.

Answer (score 1):

**First**

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
```

Return a `String` and not an `int` the correct way is :

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please guess a number between 1 to 5." 
                  + "Please input your number",
                    "Guessing Game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

**Second**

You have to initialize your `user_Number` and to concatenate it with your String you have to put the result between `(user_Number - random_Number)`

And `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` return a `void` so you can't be assign it to any variable :

```
user_Number = 0;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The difference between my number and your number is " 
                + (user_Number - random_Number),
                "Guessing Game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: The problem is solved and thanks for your help @YCF_L.

Answer (score 0):

For the second error, you need to use like following

"The difference between my number and your number is " + (user_Number - random_Number)

then `(user_Number - random_Number)` will be string lateral. Else it will try to use `-` on string which is not allowed..

And for the first problem check the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html). There is no `INFORMATION_DIALOG` there

Comment: The problem is solved and thanks for your help @StinePike.

Answer (score 0):

The first error indicates that `INFORMATION_DIALOG` is not a member of JOptionPane. This could be because you imported the *wrong* JOptionPane, or perhaps there is a typo (or there really is not `INFORMATION_DIALOG` there)

The second error is a result of combining the string concatenation (using the `+` symbol with an arithmetic operation `-`. Due to order of operations, the `+` is evaluated first, converting the value of `user_Number` into a string which is concatenated with the `"The difference between my number and your number is "` which is then interpreted as the operand in the arithmetic operation which is where your code fails. To fix this, just put the subtraction in parenthesis:

```
"The difference between my number and your number is " + (user_Number - random_Number),
```

Comment: The problem is solved and thanks for your help @Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy fix to your problem. (This will replace your difference = line of code)

```
int user_Number_As_Int = Integer.parseInt(user_Number);

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
     "The difference between my number and your number is " + (random_Number - user_Number_As_Int),
     "Guessing Game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

See, the issue with your code is that the number the user enters will be saved as a String, which, obviously, cannot be added or subtracted from an int. Furthermore, the showMethodDialouge method returns void, so you can't set difference equal to it. What this code does is changes the number the user enters to an int, and then does the subtraction. Again, you will need to REPLACE your difference = JOptionPane.showMessageDialouge line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @AGushin it solved one error but gave another error:

RandomGuessMatch.java:19: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
      int user_Number_As_Int = Integer.parseInt(user_Number);

Comment: Hey, did you change the type of user_Number to String? You need to declare it as a String instead of an int. If you did, please update your code so I can see your entire program. (I tried it on mine and it works)

Comment: I have solved the problem. @AGushin thanks for your help.